# Filter series of list by other list

Tags: python, filter

I'd like to filter a series of the list by a list. Below I presented an MWE:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2],[2,3,5]])
b = pd.Series(list(a))
```

Output desired is

```
0 [0,1,2]
```

I tried

```
b[b == [1, 2, 3]]
# and
b[b in [[1, 2, 3]]]
```

but the error message is presented `('Lengths must match to compare', (2,), (3,))`

Comment: can you explain the logic for how you got that desired output?

Comment: @Pygirl I have a dataframe and one column is composed by lists. I'd like to realize a filter getting only elements defined by a condition, in this case, `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time! I solved the problem from code below:

```
cond = [b[i]== [0, 1, 2] for i in range(b.shape[0])]
b.where(cond).dropna()
#output
0    [0, 1, 2]
dtype: object
```